# SkParagraph not shaping or rendering text

Tags: c++, macos, skia

I compiled skia for macosx using **cmake**. Everything works except SkParagraph. Can render  using canvas->drawString. Compiles and runs fine but does not wrap or show any text. Am I missing something while compiling skia?

This is what I tried,

```
 ParagraphStyle paraStyle;
 paraStyle.setTextAlign(skia::textlayout::TextAlign::kLeft);
 auto builder =
 ParagraphBuilderImpl::make(paraStyle, sk_make_sp<FontCollection>());

 builder->pushStyle(style);
 std::string text = "Hello";
 builder->addText(text.c_str(), text.length());
 builder->pop();

 // canvas->drawString("Hello", 20, 20, SkFont(), SkPaint());

 auto para = builder->Build();
 para.get()->layout(27);
 para.get()->paint(canvas, 300, 300);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/skia-discuss/skparagraph|sort:date/skia-discuss/xJEtFf7NYtY/yWBeaosNAQAJ), try setting default font manager:

```
fontCollection->setDefaultFontManager(SkFontMgr::RefDefault());
```

Also check if you have set:

- Color
- Font `style.setFontFamilies({SkString("Roboto")});`
- Width is enough